# WP Docker CLI install plugin says plugin could not be found

Tags: wordpress, docker, woocommerce, docker-compose

**Intro:**
Hi guys, can you help me troubleshoot the issue on my docker compose file. Trying the make the wp cli install command to work but it says plugin could not be found.

**Command:**
This is the command to install the plugin
`docker-compose run --rm wp plugin install woocommerce`

**Output:**
This is the warning that displays:
`Warning: woocommerce: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server&#8217;s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/forums/">support forums</a>. Warning: The 'woocommerce' plugin could not be found. Error: No plugins installed.`

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  wordpress:

services:
  site:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - wordpress

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wordpress

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    networks:
      - wordpress

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - wordpress

  wp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: wp
    entrypoint: ['wp', '--allow-root']
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

**Expectation:**
I'm expecting it to install the woocommerce plugin